# Как добавить картинку в pdf файл (после последней строки)?

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Хочу добавить картинку в pdf файл.

```
using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream("Document.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream("Approved.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);

    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);

    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

    var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

    image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
    image.Alignment = Element.HEADER;
    pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

приходится устанавливать координаты абсолютно `image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100)`;
Каким образом можно добавить картинку в pdf файл сразу после последней строки с содержимым? Или как вычислить координаты последней строки?

Answer (score 1):

добавил класс:

```
public class MarginFinder : IRenderListener
{
    private RectangleJ textRectangle = null;
    private RectangleJ currentPathRectangle = null;

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        if (textRectangle == null)
            textRectangle = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetBoundingRectange();
        else
            textRectangle.Add(renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetBoundingRectange());

        textRectangle.Add(renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetBoundingRectange());
    }

    public float GetLlx()
    {
        return textRectangle.X;
    }

    public float GetLly()
    {
        return textRectangle.Y;
    }

    public float GetUrx()
    {
        return textRectangle.X + textRectangle.Width;
    }

    public float GetUry()
    {
        return textRectangle.Y + textRectangle.Height;
    }

    public float GetWidth()
    {
        return textRectangle.Width;
    }

    public float GetHeight()
    {
        return textRectangle.Height;
    }

    public void BeginTextBlock()
    {
    }

    public void EndTextBlock()
    {
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Matrix imageCtm = renderInfo.GetImageCTM();
        Vector a = new Vector(0, 0, 1).Cross(imageCtm);
        Vector b = new Vector(1, 0, 1).Cross(imageCtm);
        Vector c = new Vector(0, 1, 1).Cross(imageCtm);
        Vector d = new Vector(1, 1, 1).Cross(imageCtm);
        LineSegment bottom = new LineSegment(a, b);
        LineSegment top = new LineSegment(c, d);
        if (textRectangle == null)
            textRectangle = bottom.GetBoundingRectange();
        else
            textRectangle.Add(bottom.GetBoundingRectange());

        textRectangle.Add(top.GetBoundingRectange());
    }


    public void ModifyPath(PathConstructionRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        List<Vector> points = new List<Vector>();
        if (renderInfo.Operation == PathConstructionRenderInfo.RECT)
        {
            float x = renderInfo.SegmentData[0];
            float y = renderInfo.SegmentData[1];
            float w = renderInfo.SegmentData[2];
            float h = renderInfo.SegmentData[3];
            points.Add(new Vector(x, y, 1));
            points.Add(new Vector(x + w, y, 1));
            points.Add(new Vector(x, y + h, 1));
            points.Add(new Vector(x + w, y + h, 1));
        }
        else if (renderInfo.SegmentData != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < renderInfo.SegmentData.Count - 1; i += 2)
            {
                points.Add(new Vector(renderInfo.SegmentData[i], renderInfo.SegmentData[i + 1], 1));
            }
        }

        foreach (Vector point in points)
        {
            var point1 = point.Cross(renderInfo.Ctm);
            RectangleJ pointRectangle = new RectangleJ(point1[Vector.I1], point1[Vector.I2], 0, 0);
            if (currentPathRectangle == null)
                currentPathRectangle = pointRectangle;
            else
                currentPathRectangle.Add(pointRectangle);
        }
    }


    public Path RenderPath(PathPaintingRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        if (renderInfo.Operation != PathPaintingRenderInfo.NO_OP)
        {
            if (textRectangle == null)
                textRectangle = currentPathRectangle;
            else
                textRectangle.Add(currentPathRectangle);
        }
        currentPathRectangle = null;

        return null;
    }


    public void ClipPath(int rule)
    {
    }
}
```

и изменил свой код:

```
using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream("table.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream("Approved.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);


            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
            PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);


            var finder = parser.ProcessContent(reader.NumberOfPages, new MarginFinder());

            if (finder.GetLly() - image.Height - 40 < 0)
            {
                stamper.InsertPage(reader.NumberOfPages + 1, reader.GetPageSize(reader.NumberOfPages));
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(reader.GetPageSize(reader.NumberOfPages).Right - image.Width, reader.GetPageSize(reader.NumberOfPages).Top - image.Height - 40);
            }
            else
            {
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(reader.GetPageSize(reader.NumberOfPages).Right - image.Width, finder.GetLly() - image.Height - 40);
            }
            var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(reader.NumberOfPages);




            pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();

        }
```

Теперь картинка помещается на последнюю страницу после контента (текст, картинки  и тд) с отступом 40. Если картинка не влезает то создаем новую страницу и переносим картинку на следующую страницу